# SQL query and subquery on AWS redshift throwing error

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

When I tried to query a table using this SQL code on AWS redshift:

```
SELECT aa.* 
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM abc.xyz_tab1) AS aa 
WHERE 
    aa.claimnumber="H02799";
```

I got the following error:

> ERROR: 42703: column "h02799" does not exist in aa

I even tried:

```
SELECT aa.* 
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM abc.xyz_tab1) aa 
WHERE aa.claimnumber = "H02799";

SELECT aa.* 
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM abc.xyz_tab1) AS aa 
WHERE claimnumber = "H02799";

SELECT aa.* 
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM abc.xyz_tab1) aa 
WHERE claimnumber = "H02799";
```

But got the same error.

What have I missed or doing wrong here?

Comment: Use single quotes: `aa.claimnumber='H02799'`.

Comment: I am not sure, but this worked. I wonder is AWS redshift sensitive towards single or double quotes???

Comment: I'm not familiar with redshift, but in ANSI SQL double quotes are used for object identifiers, and single quotes for literal strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL, string constants need to be enclosed in single quotes `'`. Double quotes are used for identifiers (column, table names).

So you need:

```
WHERE aa.claimnumber = 'H02799';
```